# Terminology for property of two branches of a tree

Tags: terminology, trees

Consider a tree $T$. A branch $B$ of a tree $T$ is just a proper subtree of $T$ (that is a subtree $B \subset T$ and $B \neq T$). Lets consider $B_1$ and $B_2$, two branches of a tree such that $B_1$ is not a subtree of $B_2$ and $B_2$ is not a subtree of $B_1$. Is there a terminology, a specific wording, to qualify such a relation between two branches?

The expression "disjoint" seems natural to me, but I'm not sure if it is used often and it may not be the best (for example the property is true for two branches with the same root, but those branches are connected, so "disjoint" might be a bit confusing for this special case.)

Comment: That is not the usual meaning of *branch*.

Comment: Could you share the usual definition of a branch ? I could not find references.

Comment: Ah, I found the definition on Wolfram Alpha:  a branch at a point $u$ in a tree is a maximal subtree containing $u$ as an endpoint. I guess I forgot the _maximal_ part. The question is not relevant with this definition though.

Comment: You’re still missing the most important part: it’s *linear*, i.e., non-branching. For a finite tree it’s a path from the root to a leaf. And by definition no branch can be a subset of another.

Comment: Hmm, interesting. Your definition is not the one given on Wolfram Mathworld (sorry not Alpha). The reference given is (Harary 1994, p. 35). The definition might change a bit from publication to publication I guess.